# jquery pan zoom not working with dynamic loaded data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I used `jquery panzoom` options with my image. It is now working with modal popup while the data are replaced on run time inside the modal content. If I statically placed the content it is working.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Panning-Zooming-Any-Elements-panzoom.html

For separate file its working fine. I want to open the image in modal popup with pan zoom options.

I used the following code:

HTML::

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="modal.php" data-target="#splModal" data-target="#flips">popup here</a>



<div class="modal fade" id="splModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

So inside the modal-content class the data from `modal.php` is replaced.

Script used in modal.php::

```
 <script src="jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

        (function() {
    alert('aa');
    var $section = $('#inverted-contain, #inverted-contain1');
    $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
    $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
    $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
    $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
    $reset: $section.find(".reset"),
    //startTransform: 'scale(1.1)',
    increment: 0.1,
    minScale: 1,
    contain: 'invert'
    }).panzoom('zoom');
    })();
```